# How to modify the scale of x and y axes of image pixel plot object from spatstat package in R

Tags: r, spatstat

I have this image pixel object, created using Spatstat package in R. The range of x-axis is [0,24], the range of y-axis is [28000, 29500]. When I plot it out in R studio, the graph looks very narrow as below: [image]

I guess it is because the range of x-axis is too small compared to y's. What should I do to make the plot wider?

Comment: You have an image that is 25 pixels wide and 1500 tall, so its aspect ratio is 1:60. What is the image of? Does it make sense to stretch it out? Your three options are to either stretch out the x axis with interpolation, squash the y axis with aggregation, or find another plotting method. However, you need to bear in mind that if you stretch out the x axis to make your image square, you will have "pixels" that are 60 times wider than they are tall. Is this really what you want? You haven't provided any other information, so it's difficult to give you any better advice here.

Comment: @AllanCameron I guess having pixels that are 60 times wider will do it.

Answer (score 1):

In the `spatstat` package, spatial objects are always plotted isometrically. The plot uses the same physical scale for the *x* and *y* axes.

Spatial objects in `spatstat` occupy a specific location and size in two-dimensional space. A pixel image (object of class `"im"`) is associated with a rectangular region at a specific location in two-dimensional space with a specific width and height. If this region is long and thin, then the plotted image will be displayed as long and thin, and will not be rescaled to fit the screen or page.

If you want to stretch a pixel image in `spatstat`, you need to transform it to another image, which will be defined on a different region of two-dimensional space.

You can do that with the `spatstat` function `affine`. In your example, if `Z` is your original pixel image, you could do

```
A <- affine(Z, diag(c(60,1)))
```

The second argument is the transformation matrix, which in this case is just a stretch of the *x* axis by a factor of 60. (The transformation will stretch the domain of the image, and stretch each individual pixel, by a factor of 60 in the *x* direction. The number of pixels and the pixel values will be unchanged. No interpolation or other fudging will occur.)

See Chapters 3 and 4 in [the spatstat book](https://book.spatstat.org)